# JFrame class convert to a NetBeans Designer support JFrame class

Tags: java, swing, jframe, netbeans-7

I'm working on `Swing` application and I'm using my IDE as `Eclipse`. Eclipse doesn't have a `Swing UI Designer Tool` according to my knowledge. Now this application is getting complex.
So I want to use a UI Designer Tool. 
When I open my JFrame classes in `Netbeans` it doesn't provide me a UI Designer. 
I thought I could use `Netbeans`, but `Netbeans` keeps it's own codes in order to support the UI Design.

Is there a way to convert regular `JFrame` class to `Netbeans UI Designer` compatible `JFrame` class ?

Comment: Even if you could get Netbeans to open your component in the UI Designer, I wouldn't do it.  It's OK for quick-and-dirty mockups, but it really starts getting in the way when you want more precise control over your layout.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, Eclipse does have a Swing UI Designer Tool indeed. It is call [WindowBuilder Pro](http://www.eclipse.org/windowbuilder/download.php) and you can update your Eclipse to include it easily. The manual is [here](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.wb.doc.user/html/index.html).

WindowBuilder Pro is very stable and runs on any platform Eclipse supports. It may not be as well integrated to Eclipse, as Matisse GUI builder is in Netbeans, but you can do your development without any problems and limitations with both.

You can do almost anything with both plug-ins. Both are flexible and expandable if you learn how to work with them.

Conversions of Swing applications between Eclipse and Netbeans are not very easy. You have to select one environment and stick to it.

GUI builders do not substitute basic Swing knowledge. It is always best for beginners to write their Swing code, using a regular editor, until they understand the concepts and the mechanics of Swing. Once you have passed this stage, if you need to write a large application, are much better off with a GUI builder than without. You can move from the prototype to the real application quickly. It allows fast modifications and adjustments of your components.

After all it is the programmer that makes the good program. Tools are just there for your convenience.

Comment: Good explanation. I got some errors on `Eclipse 3.7` while opening `JFrame` classes via `WindowsBuilder`. I just updated my Eclipse 3.7 to 4.2. `Windows Builder` is fine enough. Thanks!